# Propel: Undefined method when trying to create child object

Tags: php, inheritance, propel

Propel Version: **1.6.7**

I am getting a `PropelException` when I try to run the following code in my application (this code runs in a class called `AdminController` under a controller action). The code in question tries to create a new `ContentPage` object, which is a sub class of the `Page` class and using Propel's **Concrete Table Inheritance**:

```
$page = new ContentPage;
$page->fromData($_POST); // Modified, more secure version of fromArray();
$page->save();
```

With the exception being:

> Call to undefined method: getPage

With the method called within the Propel generated method `getParentOrCreate` in the Propel generated class `BaseContentPage`.

```
//this prevent issue with deep copy & save parent object
if (null === ($parent = $this->getPage($con))) {
```

My `schema.xml` file looks like this:

```
<!-- Page -->
<table name="page" phpName="Page">
  (columns)
</table>

<!-- ContentPage : Page -->
<table name="contentpage" phpName="ContentPage">
  <behavior name="concrete_inheritance">
    <parameter name="extends" value="page" />
  </behavior>
</table>
```

Is there something wrong in my `schema.xml` code, or is this a bug that you guys have seen and worked around?

Comment: Can we see more of the code around the line that's generating the error?  It's inside of another class, but without seeing that class it's hard to see what's throwing the error.

Comment: DaOrge, you mean in my first example? That's pretty much it really. The '...' segment is just really a modified version of the `$page->fromArray($_POST)` call. The code sits in a controller action. I've appended my question with what I've just described. 

The main concern is the `getPage` function doesn't exist anywhere in the generated classes or in the rest of the solution because it's not being generated by Propel (Propel should be generating the `getPage` method since it's generating the call to it).

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Can you do a print_r of your $this object before you run $this->getPage and verify that it's the same object type you expect it to be, then check the resulting base class for the getPage method?  If that doesnt work try posting as much code as you can on a GitHub and linking and I'll take a look

Answer (score 1):

Your schema is probably o.k. but I stumbled upon the same error today.
I found a workaround and created an issue on github.
In short, it's commenting out three lines of code in the concrete_inheritance behavior source code, regenerating the models, and if you haven't done it, update the database.

https://github.com/propelorm/PropelBundle/issues/206